# Require Vue component in JS

Tags: vue.js, electron

I am creating an object that contains Vue components.

I am having issues when I am requiring a Vue component via a string vs directly as the argument.

```js
// Not working
const vueComponentPath = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\about-page.vue'
const vueComponent = require(vueComponentPath).default

componentsToMount[componentName] = vueComponent
```

Throws out an error:

```js
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\about-page.vue'
```

While this is working well:

```js
// Working
const vueComponent = require('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\about-page.vue').default
componentsToMount[componentName] = vueComponent
```

I don't understand why my first example doesn't work. I need `require` to accept my string path.

I also tried the following but all gave out the same error message:

```js
const vueComponentPath = 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/about-page.vue'

const vueComponent = require(vueComponentPath).default
componentsToMount[componentName] = vueComponent
```

And

```js
const vueComponentPath = 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/about-page.vue'

const vueComponent = require(path.resolve(vueComponentPath)).default
componentsToMount[componentName] = vueComponent
```

Comment: It should be Node that supports this dynamic loading, and the web front end is best written with static module names.

Comment: @jeremyjone both are totally fine if used dynamically.

Comment: I mean... Do you have a specific reason not to use es6 imports or relative paths instead?
Usually you can just use `import Component from '@/components/Component.vue'` or `const Component = () => import("./Component.vue")`

Comment: @ThibautMaurice yes. Basically, this code will be put in a Vue component that will programatically load markdown files and then its respective supplemental Vue component, if applicable. So something like [about-page.md + about-page.vue] then another md file: [status-page.md but no vue file for it]. So it has to be loaded programatically, dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works okay now.

Required using relative path.

```
const vueComponent = require('../about-page.vue').default
componentsToMount[componentName] = vueComponent
```